# Use Rational Canonical form to compute conjugacy classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Use the rational canonical form to determine all conjugacy classes of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$

I know for a given conjugacy class in $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$, pick any representative $A$, we have $$\mathbb{F}_{3 A}^2\simeq \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(f_1)\oplus\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(f_2)\oplus\dots\oplus \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(f_n).$$ Such form is unique for each conjugacy class. But I don't see how I can find all conjugacy classes based on this invariant factor decomposition

Comment: Do you understand that there is a one-to-one correspondence between conjugacy classes and RCFs? So you need to work out what different types of rational canonical form can occur. Remembering that $f_1 \mid \dotsb \mid f_n$ and $f_i$ are all monic in the RCF, how many possible sequences $f_1, \dotsc, f_n$ are there?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yup I know how to do it.